# html image will not load on webpage

Tags: html

I am having trouble getting an html image to load on my webpage. the file name is Chicago skyline and the file path is: C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\Saved Pictures. I have tried using  and the page comes up blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your webpage hosted?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```html
<img src="C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Chicago skyline.jpg">
```